# How do I delete certain elements of my list?

Tags: python, list

So I've got a list that looks like this: `['87','88','89',...,'98','99']`.

I want to check if there's a a number in this list that can be paired, like '89' and '98'. If there's such a number, I would want to remove it from the list and determine the length of the customised list. I've tried this but without success:

```
for j in range(len(list)):
    if list[j][::-1] in list:
        length -= 1
```

The customised list should look something like this: `['87','88','89',...,'97','99']`

I've set the length of my list at the beginning of my code equal to 0 so my variable isn't the problem. Can someone help me with this problem? I'm pretty new to Python. Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"I've set the length of my list at the beginning of my code equal to 0"_ Why not set it to the actual length of your list? Please provide a [mre] of your problem so that we can reproduce it. Do you want the modified list or do you want just the length of the modified list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form new list with only first elements from reverse pairs.

```
myList = ['87','88','89','98','99']
newList = []
for el in myList:
  if el[::-1] not in newList:
    newList.append(el)
print(len(newList))
```

Or complex check for original list

```
myList = ['87','88','89','98','99']
for el in myList[:]:
  if el in myList and el[::-1] in myList and el != el[::-1]:
    myList.remove(el[::-1])
print(len(myList))
```

Or only length finding. Counting each pair twice, because condition is true for first and second elements in pair.

```
myList = ['87','88','89','98','99']
pairsCount = 0
for el in myList[:]:
  if el in myList and el[::-1] in myList and el != el[::-1]:
    pairsCount += 1
print(len(myList) - pairsCount // 2)
```

Comment: Your answer would be more helpful if you provided some explanation of why you did it this way (see [answer])

Comment: @re-za I wrote code by example. In example first element in pairs saved. I checked second code with remove.

Comment: @re-za add '97' to list and result will be right.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The code by complex check has made my code work!

Answer (score 0):

What I can think of is something like what follows:

```py
myList = ['87','88','89','98','99']
[x for i,x in enumerate(myList) if x[::-1] not in myList[:i]]
```

##### Output

```
['87', '88', '89', '99']
```

Note that, in this answer, numbers like `99` will not be selected in the output since their corresponding palindromes are themselves.

And If you are interested in the length of the list, you can do something like:

```py
len([x for i,x in enumerate(myList) if x[::-1] not in myList[:i]])
```

##### Output

```
4
```

Comment: I don't think they want palindromes removed.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Thanks for the comment. *If there's such a number, I would want to remove it from the list and determine the length of the customised list* I think the reason that OP has used `[::-1]` in his code is that he/she is interested in removing palindromes from the list.

Comment: They show the expected output in the question; it contains palindromes.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Right, but still, I believe the OP wanted to show that the output is a list, and it's not indicating the **ACTUAL** output. Anyway, I hope he/she answers your comment. In that case, we can answer the question more efficiently.

Comment: Now I agree with both of you. I misunderstood the problem, but just edited the answer as per your comments. @re-za

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani I'm gonna delete. This was a badly written question from the beginning

Comment: I suggest you leave your answer undeleted. You put effort and time that deserves to be seen. Maybe your answer is the correct one. @re-za

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to keep the palindromes like `"88"`:

```
new_list = []
for v in my_list:
    if v[::-1] == v:
        new_list.append(v)
    elif v[::-1] not in my_list:
        new_list.append(v)

print(len(new_list))
```

**Example**

```
my_list = ['87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99']
```

**Output**

```
['87', '88', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '99']
```

Both `"89"` and `"98"` are removed but palindromes like `"88"` are kept.

Comment: And note that the OP does not want `89` to get removed.

Comment: @AmirhosseinKiani I'm gonna delete. This was a badly written question from the beginning